# Which Game Programming API?

Tags: java

So I was just curious, I am starting to learn how to develop games in Java and was interested, which graphics API (Application Programming Interface) would one use to develop games? I have seen a few out there (including engines, that do a substantial amount of the work for you) such as:

```
Java3D 
JMonkeyEngine 

Java OpenGL
```

And I was wondering, what others are out there and what is a generally good Graphics API to start out with? I am going to start out with programming 2D games and I hope to move over to 3D game programming, so I would like to know about Graphics API's that support both 2D and 3D.
Maybe even add in what your experiences were with your selected API. Just curious

Comment: I am pretty sure that the Graphics APIs out there will support 2 and 3D.

Comment: You may get a better response @ http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I just start my search about this issue ,so i liked to start from here

Comment: Questions that start "So I was just curious" generally aren't good fits for Stack Overflow. Do you research, try to get started, and when you get stuck with a particular problem, ask you specific question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend slick 2D for the starters.
http://slick.cokeandcode.com/

I's based on LWJGL, and still let's you use it if you need it.
It has a decent documentation, demos, code samples, active froums, and useful tools made for it (just to name some - particle editors, built in support for tiled maps).

When you feel confident enough with 2D games (should take some years :) ), then switch to the jmonkeyengine for 3D games (if you really insist on Java)

Good luck